HVAC sometimes gently blowing cold air even with thermostat off
I just bought a new house in Texas from Lennar. When I turn the heating off, after a while, all of a sudden HVAC begins to gently blow cold outside air though the return vent. After a while it stops (albeit by then the temperature would have plummeted by 4 degrees). Then it does it again. And again. What's going on?

Some/most heating systems have a cool down mode/blower keeps working once it stops heating/burning.  It should last just a few minutes till the system temp sensors drop.

Doesn't seem to me like it applies to this situation. It blows that cold air even with the thermostat off for the entire day.

Most typical HVAC blowers are "squirrel cage" style, meaning they're one way blowers: they cannot reverse. So it's something else that's getting air to come out of the return vent. Do you have an HRV or ERV or some other blowers besides the main furnace that could be turning on our failing to turn off?

It's a stir setting, and it's sampling the air. RTM of your T-Stat.

@triplefault Yes, there is an HRV

ERV by AprilAire

It's true that some thermostats have a feature to run the fan periodically even when there's no call for heat or cooling, or even in "off" mode. But that won't (*shouldn't!) cause air to come out through the return.

How is the ERV connected to your HVAC? What are the damper controls set to? If it is connected to your return duct and running independently of your HVAC, this doesn't seem too surprising - particularly if the ERV is set to create positive pressure (e.g. more fresh air in than exhaust out).

I know it's been a while but just in case anyone cares - I've spoken both with the HVAC company and the Lennar construction manager. They both said the same thing. It works as designed. They actually recommend to NOT have the ERV on, when the outside temperature is way different from the desired temperature in the house. They have to put in the ERVs by code but off the record they don't seem to be a big fan of them.
